# Using a table display method in a query or view

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to make a query against the table HcmWorker and related.
But i want to figure out how to get the result of the display method HcmWorker.primaryDepartmentName() into it's own field in my query.

I also tried creating a view to execute the function via a ViewMethod but that doesn't seem to work as ViewMethods only inject code into the final query against the view.

I'm NOT making a form. The end result has to come through the QueryService.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but what you are trying to do is not possible.

You could calculate a non stored field in the `postLoad` method, but that would impact every access to your table, and it would most likely not work in the context of a query service.

Comment: Thats ashame :( Do you hapen to know the exact chain of joins to get the same result? Iwe been staring at the charts for days and cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your primary problem is that `Department` is time effective dependent. This is representable as a query, but not as view (because a view cannot depend on a runtime parameter). In your view select the same tabels as in the `getDepartments` method. Potentially this may return more than one department for a given time.