# How to use display method as field in the query

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need query with 2 fields - InventTable.ItemId, and InventTable.itemName().
How to add/use InventTable.itemName() in the query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a table display method in a query or view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483438/using-a-table-display-method-in-a-query-or-view)

Comment: Could you please explain how would you like to use this query. Why do you need this display method?

Comment: I realized that my approach was wrong and decided that i don't need this display method in the query because i can always find ItemName using ItemId. So i just was wrong asking this question as in the earlier existing similar question i could not find solution

Answer (score 1):

InventTable.itemName() is not a field of that table, is a method. You always should search the real field underneath, add the related tables to the query and then add the field to that query, whichever it is.

Comment: of course i understand that InventTable.itemName() is a method. I need data that this method returns. But this method has the logic inside, so how can i provide this logic to the query?

Comment: Since the result of that "logic" is not a value that is actually in the database you need to use a different approach than a query (like the option of using the ItemId later). There is another option, creating a view and use a "computed column", but I suppose that is not suitable for your needs.